# Unable to run several SQL update statements in Java

Tags: java, sql

I am still quite new to the world of java. I am working on my second application which is a program that mass updates a time field in my company's SQL database. I am able to run queries through java, and store each query line in a resultset just fine. The thing is that each line of the result set is an update statement. I want to then run those resultset lines. However over and over I keep getting the "SQL command not properly ended" error message when I know full well these statements are formatted correctly and run just fine in TOAD for oracle. Can anyone help me understand whats going on here?  I have also tried batching and continue to get the same error.

This is an example of one of the output lines of my query with table and field names changed.

```
Update sometable.somefield set COMPLETED_TS ='31-OCT-17 06.00.00.000000000 AM'Where eqact_id ='2559340';
```

Below you can see the end of my SQL string and my runScript2() method.

```
            "\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            "where \"Center\" = S.CODE and S.TIMEZONE_ID = T.ID"; //This String is named SQL1

    public void runScript2(){
        try {

        PreparedStatement statement0 = Connection1.conn.prepareStatement(SQL1);

        ResultSet result0 = statement0.executeQuery();


        Connection1.conn.setAutoCommit(false);

        while(result0.next()) {

            PreparedStatement statementq1=Connection1.conn.prepareStatement(result0.getString(1));
            statementq1.executeUpdate();


        }


        Connection1.conn.commit();



    }catch (SQLException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();

}

}
```

Comment: result0.getString(1) must not be returning the query in right format

Comment: What's the database?

Answer (score 0):

Well I am angry and happy at the same time as I figured out that the issue was that my result0.getString(1) lines had a semicolon at the end of each and for some reason Java didn't like this. They run just fine without this.

Live and you learn I guess.